# Nginx rewrite URLs but not static files

Tags: nginx, rewrite, static-files

I need to rewrite URLs like

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/this-is-a-static-file.jpg
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/this-is-a-static-file.jpg
```

I am using this rule:

```
location /blog/wp-content$ {
        rewrite ^/blog/wp-content/(.*)$ /wp-content$1 last;
}
```

The weird thing is that only URLs directly behind wp-content and without static files are rewritten correctly:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/ => http://www.migayopruebas.com/wp-content/uploads/
```

However, it there are more than one sub level OR a static file is involved, it doesn't work:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/migayo-trangulacion-laton.jpg => doesn't change
```

http://www.domain.com/blog/wp-content/migayo-trangulacion-laton.jpg => doesn't change

Could anyone point me out to the right way to do this? I've been read Nginx doc and several examples and still can't make it work.

Thanks a lot, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work, because you don't have a regex `location` (the `~` character is missing), and you end the location with the `$`, which is a regex character.

You can do it in a bit simpler way:

```
location ~ /blog/wp-content/(?<filename>.+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /wp-content/$filename last;
}
```

So, here you do the regex capture in the `location` directive, and use the captured part of the path with the `rewrite` destination.

If you want to make a client side 301 redirect, use the following:

```
location ~ /blog/wp-content/(?<filename>.+)$ {
    rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/wp-content/$filename permanent;
}
```

Comment: I would include the slash after wp-content in the location so it doesn't match unexpectedly.

Comment: It works, thank you very much :) I am surprised to see that despite the links work, the URL in the browser bar doesn't change. Do you know if I can force the change in the URL? Regards and thanks again.

Comment: Edited answer to provide client side redirect which changes browser URL.

Comment: Work like a charm. Your answer goes straight to Evernote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

(I post an answer because >50 reputation is needed to comment)

Why the "$" ?

You probably want this:

```
location /blog/wp-content/ {
        rewrite ^/blog/wp-content/(.*)$ /wp-content$1 last;
}
```